# Convert XML to CSV-like structure

Tags: xml

i have a xml data like below

```
<Open>
        <ID>7171</ID>
        <Name>REENU</Name>
        <Description>CHUMMA</Description>
        <Active>1</Active>
        <Users>1</Users>
</Open>

<Open>
        <ID>7172</ID>
        <Name>BEENU</Name>
        <Description>CHUMMA</Description>
        <Active>1</Active>
        <Users>1</Users>
</Open>

<Open>
        <ID>7173</ID>
        <Name>CEENU</Name>
        <Description>CHUMMA</Description>
        <Active>1</Active>
        <Users>1</Users>
</Open>

<Open>
        <ID>7174</ID>
        <Name>DEENU</Name>
        <Description>CHUMMA</Description>
        <Active>1</Active>
        <Users>1</Users>
</Open>

<Open>
        <ID>7175</ID>
        <Name>GEENU</Name>
        <Description>CHUMMA</Description>
        <Active>1</Active>
        <Users>1</Users>
</Open>
```

i want to convert into csv using UNIX commands like below using unix commands
basically i want to print the middle value of the xml tag

```
Open,7171,REENU,CHUMMA,1,1
Open,7172,BEENU,CHUMMA,1,1
Open,7173,CEENU,CHUMMA,1,1
Open,7174,DEENU,CHUMMA,1,1
Open,7175,GEENU,CHUMMA,1,1
```

Comment: Please, format your question. A more descriptive title would be great, too.

Comment: [Just do it.](http://lithe.files.wordpress.com/2008/05/nike-just-do-it.jpg)

Comment: This is trivial in XSLT.  Do you have an XSLT processor available?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ nawk '/<\/Open>/{print ""}{gsub(/<.[^>]*>/,"");printf "%s, ",$0} ' file | sed -e 's/^[ \t,]*/Open,/' -e 's/,[ \t]*/,/g' -e 's/,$//'
Open,7171,REENU,CHUMMA,1,1
Open,7172,BEENU,CHUMMA,1,1
Open,7173,CEENU,CHUMMA,1,1
Open,7174,DEENU,CHUMMA,1,1
```